# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =' on optional parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to add ngrx/store to my Angular app. A lot of tutorials/introductions go over a simple counter with a reducer function that looks like:

```
export const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "INCREMENT":
            return state + 1;
        case "DECREMENT":
            return state - 1;
        case "RESET":
            return state = 0;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my app, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Does anyone know why this is happening? It complains about the second '=' sign, the optional parameter. My current package.json has typescript version '^2.2.1'

Comment: It works for me, tsc version `Version 2.5.0-dev.20170629`

Comment: I'm seeing the problem on you RESET case, try to firstly set state = 0 and then returns it.

Comment: Optional parameters should never come before required parameters, that could be the issue.

Comment: @Kadima, the spec permits it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters

Comment: @AnthonySottile no it doesn't. It explicitly says `Any optional parameters must follow required parameters`.

Comment: @Aron you're conflating "optional" and "default" parameters. fta: Unlike plain optional parameters, default-initialized parameters don’t need to occur after required parameters. If a default-initialized parameter comes before a required parameter, users need to explicitly pass undefined to get the default initialized value.

Comment: @AnthonySottile you're right. Still, is it possible that an earlier version of TS doesn't allow it?

Comment: @Aron, I don't see it mentioned in any changelogs back to typescript1.1 (released in late 2014)

Comment: @Aron I upgrade my TypeScript version to 2.4.1 and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Jsfiddle. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/tardycorgi9917/egt9sw2d/

Just have to set state to 0 then return. Also, you should always have a default switch in case nothing matches and optional parameters have to be at the end (In typescript docs).

```
export const counter = (action, state = 0) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return ++state;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return --state;
    case "RESET":
      return (state = 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link for the fiddle?

Comment: This does seem to work - but why does an error further down in the function cause a syntax error with the function parameters?

Comment: It's because of the parser, It reads left to right so it saw "return state" and it was ok let me return state. then it saw the = sign when it was expecting a semicolon or newline. Adding parenthesis fixed this as what is inside it evaluated before

Comment: Doesn't work on my end - I get the same error - maybe because I'm using TypeScript. I'll remove the JS tag.

Comment: @Roka545 I just tried it on the typescript playground and it works. In what context is this being called?

Comment: That function is a reducer function for ngrx/store (not sure if you're familiar with that). I call my ngrx/store store dispatch call with INCREMENT, DECREMENT, or RESET and that function gets called. However, I get the error I mentioned whenever it is called.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510. I found this. Scroll down to the sample reducer. Does this work?

Comment: No - I get the same error - there seems to be something about my project setup or installed libraries that is causing this. Almost every tutorial I've seen has the same function setup, yet my system doesn't like it.

Comment: I would recommend checking your project for another definition of counter. Very possible to functions are conflicting each other.